# Suppress warning "'heatmap' objects don't have these attributes: 'mode'"

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, ggmap, ggplotly

The following Shiny app combining ggmap and plotly with heatmap:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plotly)
require(ggmap)
require(shiny)

server = function(input, output, session, module_input) {
  
  output$map = renderPlotly({
    
    d = data.frame(lon = rnorm(1e5, mean = mean(c(-125, -66)), sd=4),
                   lat = rnorm(1e5, mean = mean(c(25, 50)), sd=4)) 

    bb = list(bottom = 25, left = -125, top = 50, right = -66)
    basemap = get_stamenmap(bbox = unlist(bb), zoom = 4, maptype = 'toner-lite')
    
    p = ggmap(basemap) +
      stat_bin2d(data = d, aes(lon, lat), alpha = 0.75, drop = TRUE) +
      scale_fill_continuous(low = 'grey95', high = 'red')
    
    ggplotly(p)
  })
}


ui = function() {
  plotlyOutput('map', width = '100vw', height = '100vh')
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = FALSE))
```

[image]

.. works fine but generates a confusing and unnecessary warning that is clogging up my error logs.  Have tried `suppressWarnings` around the plotly call, `shinyApp()` call, and even the whole script without success (knowing the latter of these two would be bad practice).  Any other ideas?

```
Warning: 'heatmap' objects don't have these attributes: 'mode'
Valid attributes include:
'autocolorscale', 'coloraxis', 'colorbar', 'colorscale', 'connectgaps', 'customdata', 'customdatasrc', 'dx', 'dy', 'hoverinfo', 'hoverinfosrc', 'hoverlabel', 'hoverongaps', 'hovertemplate', 'hovertemplatesrc', 'hovertext', 'hovertextsrc', 'ids', 'idssrc', 'legendgroup', 'legendgrouptitle', 'legendrank', 'meta', 'metasrc', 'name', 'opacity', 'reversescale', 'showlegend', 'showscale', 'stream', 'text', 'textsrc', 'transforms', 'transpose', 'type', 'uid', 'uirevision', 'visible', 'x', 'x0', 'xaxis', 'xcalendar', 'xgap', 'xhoverformat', 'xperiod', 'xperiod0', 'xperiodalignment', 'xsrc', 'xtype', 'y', 'y0', 'yaxis', 'ycalendar', 'ygap', 'yhoverformat', 'yperiod', 'yperiod0', 'yperiodalignment', 'ysrc', 'ytype', 'z', 'zauto', 'zhoverformat', 'zmax', 'zmid', 'zmin', 'zsmooth', 'zsrc', 'key', 'set', 'frame', 'transforms', '_isNestedKey', '_isSimpleKey', '_isGraticule', '_bbox'

Warning: 'heatmap' objects don't have these attributes: 'mode'
Valid attributes include:
'autocolorscale', 'coloraxis', 'colorbar', 'colorscale', 'connectgaps', 'customdata', 'customdatasrc', 'dx', 'dy', 'hoverinfo', 'hoverinfosrc', 'hoverlabel', 'hoverongaps', 'hovertemplate', 'hovertemplatesrc', 'hovertext', 'hovertextsrc', 'ids', 'idssrc', 'legendgroup', 'legendgrouptitle', 'legendrank', 'meta', 'metasrc', 'name', 'opacity', 'reversescale', 'showlegend', 'showscale', 'stream', 'text', 'textsrc', 'transforms', 'transpose', 'type', 'uid', 'uirevision', 'visible', 'x', 'x0', 'xaxis', 'xcalendar', 'xgap', 'xhoverformat', 'xperiod', 'xperiod0', 'xperiodalignment', 'xsrc', 'xtype', 'y', 'y0', 'yaxis', 'ycalendar', 'ygap', 'yhoverformat', 'yperiod', 'yperiod0', 'yperiodalignment', 'ysrc', 'ytype', 'z', 'zauto', 'zhoverformat', 'zmax', 'zmid', 'zmin', 'zsmooth', 'zsrc', 'key', 'set', 'frame', 'transforms', '_isNestedKey', '_isSimpleKey', '_isGraticule', '_bbox'
```

Comment: How about [`purrr::quietly()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/safely.html)?

Comment: Doesn't support shiny/plotly sorts of object it seems

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that these warnings are not thrown by `ggplotly()`, but rather its `print()` method. When you run `suppressWarnings(ggplotly(p))` the warnings still appear, because the implicit printing is not wrapped in `suppressWarnings()`. But if you make the printing explicit, then suppression works:

`suppressWarnings(print(ggplotly(p)))` does not yield any warnings.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't actually work for me, but wrapping around the `shinyApp(..)` call does. This feels dangerous as I'll miss all warnings that occur in production, but I suppose it might be the only solution.  WIll leave question open for a while otherwise will accept this.

Comment: Sorry, deleted the comment because I was mistaken. It actually still did appear on my machine as well

Comment: Or rather in did appear once I set `launch.browser = T`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the workaround provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019212/suppress-plotly-warnings-in-shiny-app/39029683#39029683) which disables the warning only for a short time during the plot:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(plotly)
require(ggmap)
require(shiny)

server = function(input, output, session, module_input) {
  
  output$map = renderPlotly({
    # suppress warnings  
    storeWarn<- getOption("warn")
    options(warn = -1) 
    
    d = data.frame(lon = rnorm(1e5, mean = mean(c(-125, -66)), sd=4),
                   lat = rnorm(1e5, mean = mean(c(25, 50)), sd=4)) 
    
    bb = list(bottom = 25, left = -125, top = 50, right = -66)
    basemap = get_stamenmap(bbox = unlist(bb), zoom = 4, maptype = 'toner-lite')
    
    p = ggmap(basemap) +
      stat_bin2d(data = d, aes(lon, lat), alpha = 0.75, drop = TRUE) +
      scale_fill_continuous(low = 'grey95', high = 'red')
    
    #restore warnings, delayed so plot is completed
    shinyjs::delay(expr =({ options(warn = storeWarn) }) ,ms = 100) 
    
    ggplotly(p)
  })
}


ui = function() {
  plotlyOutput('map', width = '100vw', height = '100vh')
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = FALSE))
```